# Are there inherent problems to using multiple filters in one line of a gitattributes file?

Tags: git, sed, gitattributes

Can you have multiple git attributes per line in the .gitattributes file? And if so what order do they get executed in?

I've been seeing some weird behavior where they're not getting executed in the fashion that one might expect.

Here's an example of one of my .gitattributes files that I am referring to:

```
app*.php filter=infosafe_smudge_test filter=infosafe_smudge_test_staging filter=infosafe_clean_live filter=infosafe_clean_test filter=infosafe_clean_staging filter=infosafe_clean_test_staging filter=infosafe_global
/tests/config/framework.php filter=path_test
.gitattributes merge=ours
```

Then in my repo's git config file I have:

```
[filter "infosafe_clean_test"]
    clean = ../filters/sensitive_values_remover_test.sh
[filter "infosafe_clean_live"]
    clean = ../filters/sensitive_values_remover_live.sh
[filter "infosafe_clean_staging"]
    clean = ../filters/sensitive_values_remover_staging.sh
[filter "infosafe_clean_test_staging"]
    clean = ../filters/sensitive_values_remover_test_staging.sh
[filter "infosafe_smudge_test"]
    smudge = ../filters/sensitive_values_inserter_test.sh
[filter "infosafe_smudge_live"]
    smudge = ../filters/sensitive_values_inserter_live.sh
[filter "infosafe_smudge_staging"]
    smudge = ../filters/sensitive_values_inserter_staging.sh
[filter "infosafe_smudge_test_staging"]
    smudge = ../filters/sensitive_values_inserter_test_staging.sh
```

Etc.

The individual shell scripts are just one-line sed scripts with multiple -e arguments like:

```
#! /bin/sh -f 
sed \
-e 's|string to find|string to replace|' \
-e 's|string to find 2|string to replace 2| \
$1
```

Of course they are set executable and permissions are normal. All the shell scripts have been tested and so I know they work if used right on the command line.

Some of the shell scripts seem to get called by git. But not all. I don't understand it. No errors come when I re-check-out the HEAD.

What is going on? Is there something in my approach that would cause a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Darn. You can't have multiple filters per line.